# Lock Condition.notify is throwing java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, conditional-statements, locking, notify

I wrote a program to demonstrate Lock.Condition of java for multithreading purpose. I am getting IllegalMonitorStateException.

It is throwing an exception the below is output.

I am acquiring lock before calling notify on a condition. But still getting the below error. Can someone help. I googled a lot but couldn't find a solution.

```
Count : 0
lock java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@4ce4d37e[Locked by thread Thread-0]
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner
at java.base/java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
at test.OddEvenPrinter.printEven(Test.java:51)
    at test.Test.lambda$main$1(Test.java:22)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Count : 1
lock java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@4ce4d37e[Locked by thread Thread-1]
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at test.OddEvenPrinter.printOdd(Test.java:67)
    at test.Test.lambda$main$0(Test.java:14)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

The code for it is below:

```
package test;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final OddEvenPrinter oddEvenPrinter = new OddEvenPrinter();
        Runnable oddRunnable = () -> {
            try {
                while (true)
                    oddEvenPrinter.printOdd();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        Runnable evenRunnable = () -> {
            try {
                while (true)
                    oddEvenPrinter.printEven();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        new Thread(evenRunnable).start();
        new Thread(oddRunnable).start();
    }
}

class OddEvenPrinter {
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition oddPrint = lock.newCondition();
    private final Condition evenPrint = lock.newCondition();
    private int count;
    public void printEven() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            while (count % 2 == 1) {
                evenPrint.await();
            }
            System.out.println("Count : " + count++);
            System.out.println("lock " + lock);
            oddPrint.notify();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    public void printOdd() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            while (count % 2 == 0) {
                oddPrint.await();
            }
            System.out.println("Count : " + count++);
            System.out.println("lock " + lock);
            evenPrint.notify();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When using `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition` we should use `signal` or `signalAll` methods. The `notify` and `notifyAll` are the methods related to intrinsic locks (with the `synchronized` keyword)

Comment: I needed to use signal instead of notify. It is just a confusion with the method name.

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to miss. Intellij IDEA even has an [inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/list-of-java-inspections.html) for it, its name is "notify() or notifyAll() called on java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition object". Posted as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used notify instead of using signal method when I am using lock conditions.

I am pasting the corrected code.

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final OddEvenPrinter oddEvenPrinter = new OddEvenPrinter();
        Runnable oddRunnable = () -> {
            try {
                while (true)
                    oddEvenPrinter.printOdd();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        Runnable evenRunnable = () -> {
            try {
                while (true)
                    oddEvenPrinter.printEven();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        new Thread(evenRunnable).start();
        new Thread(oddRunnable).start();
    }
}

class OddEvenPrinter {

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    private final Condition oddPrint = lock.newCondition();

    private final Condition evenPrint = lock.newCondition();

    private int count;

    public void printEven() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            while (count % 2 == 1) {
                evenPrint.await();
            }
            System.out.println("Count : " + count++);
            System.out.println("lock " + lock);
            oddPrint.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }

    public void printOdd() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            while (count % 2 == 0) {
                oddPrint.await();
            }
            System.out.println("Count : " + count++);
            System.out.println("lock " + lock);
            evenPrint.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition` we should use `signal` or `signalAll` methods.

Example:

```java
public void foo() {
    reentrantLock.lock();
    try {
        condition.signal();
    } finally {
        reentrantLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

The `notify` and `notifyAll` are the methods related to intrinsic locks (with the `synchronized` keyword), example:

```java
public synchronized void foo() throws InterruptedException {
    this.notify();
}
```